# error: package rx.android.schedulers does not exist

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I am getting an error with rxAndroid. `error: package rx.android.schedulers does not exist after I upgraded Gradle, buildToolVersion and compileSdk.

Here is my gradle files

Main gradle file

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "com.fernandocejas.frodo:frodo-plugin:0.8.1"
        classpath 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics:androiddevmetrics-plugin:0.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
} 

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    jcenter()
}
```

app gradle file

```
compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 187
        versionName "1.0.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

dependencies {
  implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.7'
implementation group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'adapter-rxjava2', version: '2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

   implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'

}
```

My sample usage

```
//Here is the error

import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
compositeSubscription.add(publishRelay.asObservable().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(iView -> {

    }
```

I had a look online but nothing worked for me.

can any one suggest please what can be wrong.

Thanks
R

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your problem but you're using Retrofit adapters for both RxJava 1 and RxJava 2. Consider removing `com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0` from your dependencies.

Comment: You want to use RxJava2, and you don't want to use RxJava1.

Comment: hi I have added a bit of code of how I am using it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce where am I using rxjava1

Comment: `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'` is for RxJava1, and you want to use Rxjava2, see https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2

Comment: what should i change it to

Comment: @BRDroid - check my answers, That's what you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

you need change your dependency

from

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.5.0'
```